# How to populate the datatable from json object with key and value as columns

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

Normally for populating the Jquery datatable we need to give Json Array (Array of json object) to datatable and map each field with one column. But I have one json object and I want to show all the key in one column and its associated value in next colmn in same row.

For e.g. Sample json :-

```
 {
"first-name": "Tom",
"last-name": "Hanks",
"Designation": "Developer"
 }
```

Output table :-

```
             Key          Value

            first-name    Tom
            last-name     Hanks
            Designation  Developer
```

Number of these key and values may vary in future.

One simple way is that I can traverse on object and convert it into array of objects having two attributes and use to populate table.
But I was wondering if there is any other direct way.

Comment: did you try creating an array in desired form from object?

Comment: I have mentioned in question if there is other way available. I know that is one option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working for your example data:

```
var data = {
    "first-name": "Tom",
    "last-name": "Hanks",
    "Designation": "Developer"
};
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "key",
            "title": "Key"
        },
        {
            "data": "value",
            "title": "Value"
        }
    ]
});
for(var key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        table.row.add({
            "key": key,
            "value": data[key]
        });
    }
}
table.draw();
```

There is probably a more elegant solution but as a back of an envelope thing it seems to work well - should probably be done using a call back I reckon though. You can see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/r2vf2wLw/).

This is a much smaller method using a callback:

```
var data = {
    "first-name": "Tom",
    "last-name": "Hanks",
    "Designation": "Developer"
};
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [{
        "data": "key",
        "title": "Key"
    },{
        "data": "value",
        "title": "Value"
    }],
    "initComplete": function() {
        this.api().rows.add(JSON.stringify(data).slice(2, -2).split('","').map((c)=>({
            "key": c.split('":"')[0],
            "value": c.split('":"')[1]
        }))).draw();
    }
});
```